# How to mock TableResult BigQuery

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-bigquery

I'm fetching some data from **Bigquery(Google)** and the flow is working as expected.
But I'm having difficulties when making a **mock** of the TableResult.

My search in bigquery is as follows:

```
private final BigQuery bigQuery;

public TableResult findInBigQuery(Integer amountPreviousDaysProcess) {
        bigQuery.query(createQuery(amountPreviousDaysProcess, TABLE_NAME));
        return bigQuery.listTableData(TABLE_NAME, SCHEMA, BigQuery.TableDataListOption.pageSize(PAGE_SIZE));
}
```

My schema is as follows:

```
 private static final Schema SCHEMA = Schema.of(FieldList.of(Field.of("name", LegacySQLTypeName.NUMERIC),
                                                            Field.of("city", LegacySQLTypeName.STRING));
```

Do you know how I can mock/create a TableResult with this schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
private static final Page<FieldValueList> INNER_PAGE_0 = new PageImpl<>(
        new PageImpl.NextPageFetcher<FieldValueList>() {
            @Override
            public Page<FieldValueList> getNextPage() {
                return null;
            }
        },
        null,
        ImmutableList.of(newFieldValueList()));

private static final Schema SCHEMA = Schema.of(
        Field.of("field1", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
        Field.of("field2", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING));

private static FieldValueList newFieldValueList() {
    return FieldValueList.of(ImmutableList.of(
            FieldValue.of(FieldValue.Attribute.PRIMITIVE, "123"),
            FieldValue.of(FieldValue.Attribute.PRIMITIVE, "abc")));
}
```

```java
TableResult result = new TableResult(SCHEMA, 1, INNER_PAGE_0);
```

For reference: [TableResultTest](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery/blob/main/google-cloud-bigquery/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/TableResultTest.java) of Google Cloud BigQuery Client for Java